# How to add resources to custom resource files without them being placed in the default "Resources" folder in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dll, resources

How to add resources to custom resource files(.resx) without them being placed in the default "Resources" folder.

here is a screenshot of my setup

[image]

I then add a image to `ToolbarImageResources.resx` and this happens as expected. The resource get passed into the default "Resource" folder.
Most times we dont want this to happen.

[image]

If we were to move the image from the `Resource` folder and place it into the `ToolbarImageResources` folder then you will see this error message `Error    24  Resource 'ne2' could not be loaded because the file to which it is linked could not be found: YourPath\Resources\SettingsIcon.png.  YourPath\ToolbarImageResources.resx 0   0`

For this example ,how do we ensue that the resource can be placed into the `ToolbarImageResource` folder without throwing an error

Comment: Fighting the design does come with a price.  You just have to do it the other way around.  *First* add the resource to your custom folder, *then* add it as a resource by selecting it from the custom folder.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot . this was rather simple.
Are there any downfalls to using this method ? or will things function as they should ?

Comment: Other than your team members no longer inviting you for a beer or the guy that will maintain your project some day knowing where you live, no.

Comment: hahah Thanks again . I will take my chances.
I hope that others find this useful. can you post your reply as an answer so that others see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,  Add the resource to your custom folder.
Then add it as a resource by selecting it from the custom folder.